# The external (global) variables in C

Tags: c, global-variables, ansi-c

I'm reading a C programming book, *The C Programming Language (K & R, 2nd Edition)*. I got to know the facts about external variables in the book, but I found something different when I practiced the principles by myself. The book says:

> **"... because external variables remain in existence permanently, rather than appearing and disappearing as functions are called and exited, they retain their values even after the functions that set them have returned."**

However, when I code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0;
void foo();

main()
{
    foo();                  
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}

void foo()
{
    i = 1;
}
```

The program prints 1 instead of 0 which is the original value of the external variable `i`. So I wonder where I get mistakes while thinking about the principle and how to understand it.

Comment: The program is **meant** to print 1 instead of 0.

Comment: The text you cited quite clearly implies that your code should print 1, so I don't understand the issue.

Comment: My recommendation. Study [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) and read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Your book is excellent, but the C standard did evolve. Read also about [*undefined behavior*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: The cited text does not state they keep their **initial** value. It only states they keep the value after the function changing it was left.

Comment: In my copy of K&R 2nd Edition (first printing in 1988, with 'Based on Draft Proposed ANSI C' blazoned on the cover), on p74, the sentence that you seem to be quoting is _"External variables, on the other hand, are permanent, so they retain values from one function invocation to the next."_  I don't have a later version to compare that quote with.  It's mostly minor changes — but there is some difference in emphasis.

Comment: The term of art for this subject is variable "scope", if you wish to look for other examples or explainers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...they retain their values even after the functions that set them have returned.

I'm guessing it's a question of interpretation on your part.

Given that the variable is global, every time you change it, in any function, it will assume and retain that value until it is next modified.

Take the function:

```
int i = 0;
void foo();

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    foo(x);                  
    printf("%d", i);
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int x)
{
    x = 1;
    i = 1;
}
```

result: `x = 0` `i = 1`

`x` is passed by value, essentially, a copy of it, so as soon as the function goes out of scope, i.e. returns, the copy is discarded. `i` is global so you don't even need to pass it; every function is aware of its existence and will change its value.

Comment: I see, "remain the value" means after accepting the new value and remain it.

Comment: @SaeronMeng, since the variable never goes out of scope because it is global it any change in any funtion is reflected on the variable.

Comment: This is kinda confusing since you use `i` for global as well as local

Answer (score 2):

Opposite to what you think this phrase

> ...as functions are called and exited, they remain their values even
>   after the functions that set them have returned

means that after exiting a function a variables with the external linkage keeps the value assigned to it in the function.  And your program demonstrates this.

Pay attention to that now according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

There is no default type `int` of a function though some compilers keep the backward compatibility.